# Why does dependency injection not work when im using esbuild for building my Angular 17 project?

Tags: angular, esbuild

I want to migrate from "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser" to "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser" to speed up development. But the problem i get is that every time i start my application the following error gets logged in my console:

NG0203: `inject()` must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `runInInjectionContext`.

As described in the Angular docs, i simply changed "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser" to "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser-esbuild" in my angular.json file. While no errors get logged in my vs code terminal, i keep seeing this error in the console in the browser. I expected this to work, since the docs said that this would be the only change i needed to make

Comment: Please add a minimal reproducible code example of the code where the error is thrown. Also, I assume you are migrating from  `@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser` to `@angular-devkit/build-angular:application`? In your question it always says "browser".

Comment: Im migrating to browser-esbuild, my bad. 

The error seems to appear when im registering an effect like this in app.module:
`EffectsModule.forRoot([AuthEffects])`


The effect class looks like this:
`@Injectable()
export class AuthEffects {
  constructor(private actions$: Actions, private authService: AuthService) {}


  login$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(fetchUser),
      mergeMap(() =>
        this.authService.fetchUser().pipe(
          map((user) => setUser({ user })),
          catchError((error) => of())
        )
      )
    )
  );
}`

Answer (score 0):

i assume that you run Inject() function outside the class.

so that can cause the error.
In practice the inject() calls are allowed in a constructor, a constructor parameter and a field initializer.
Here is the example

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class Car {
  radio: Radio|undefined;

  // OK: field initializer
  spareTyre = inject(Tyre);
  
  constructor() {
    // OK: constructor body
    this.radio = inject(Radio);
  }
}
```

Or you can visit the angular documentation to fix the error

https://angular.io/errors/NG0203

And let me know

Comment: The error occurs because of an ngrx effect class, which annotated with @Injectable(). Which i then register with `EffectsModule.forRoot([AuthEffects])` in my app.module

Comment: is that solve the problem?? i hope so
in your comment above, i suggest you to use EMPTY instead of of() in cacthError stream. 
catchError(() => EMPTY)
it's more Idiomatic and its about personal preference and code style.

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem, it seems to cause the problem.